# Why does my partial view accept a IPagedList model but not a StaticPagedList one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, pagedlist

I have a partial view in ASP.NET MVC 5. I originally had it set up to accept a model of `PagedList.IPagedList<Object>` as I needed to pass in many different kinds of class.

`@model PagedList.IPagedList<Object>`

However, I now need to change it to accept a `StaticPagedList` model. When I implemented this like in the following:

`@model PagedList.StaticPagedList<Object>`

it created an error.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'PagedList.StaticPagedList'1[MyClass]', but this dictionary requires a
>   model item of type 'PagedList.StaticPagedList'1[System.Object]'.

Why does this happen? Why did I not get this error when I was using a regular `IPagedList`? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you have changed only the model declaration and not touched the actual model which is passed to the view?

Comment: @JakubJankowski As far as I know, yes.

Comment: @JakubJankowski And just so you know, I'm definitely passing the correct type of object to the view in the controller code.

Comment: I assume, you have something similiar to this in your code:
`var model = new StaticPagedList<YourClass> { /* your objects here */ };`
Changing this to: `var model = new StaticPagedList<Object> { /* your objects here */ };` could help, if you indeed have the code I said

Comment: @JakubJankowski I just tried it. It definitely fixed my problem, but that doesn't explain why the two `StaticPagedList` models wouldn't work with each other, whereas the `IPagedList` ones did.

Comment: seems you have use paging at controller side and return type is pagedlist

Comment: At the moment, I am clueless as well, but also I have only my phone at disposal. I'm gonna try to investigate this a little more when I'm back at home and no correct answer will present at that time

Comment: By the way, do your types inherit or implement types from System.Collections.Generic? List<T>, IList<T> or some other?

Comment: @JakubJankowski Nope. No inheritance involved.

Comment: @Ben could you post more code? I mean, both versions: with the interface and with the implementation as the models. I am not sure whether I am reproducing your situation correctly and posting this could help me